# 615 injection after PHP readfile

Tags: php, readfile

I recently included a file on a website that I was building, since the project was aimed at mobile web browsers, I used PHP readfile() to include the content of a css file on to the head section of the page. Suddenly a 615 number appeared at the end of my included content, but it was nowhere to be found on the files... so it had to be an error message of some kind.

This was the first time I came across this enigma, I've readfile()'s hundreds of times before without any trouble at all.

I did some searching on the PHP.NET site and couldn't find an unswer there, did a quick search on google and nothing.

Comment: There isn't a question here. So yeah *"This is not a question"* - you're right. Can you post one? What you should have done was post a question then an answer.

Comment: `reafile()` you realize that error reporting would've thrown an undefined function warning.

Comment: That was a typo on the question not on the code, I already edit it.
Followed your kind suggestion Funk. Thank You : )

Comment: Ah, there we go :)

Comment: Thing is though; you should have posted the code you tried to use. Maybe this has been asked before but didn't know what to look for. As it stands, the question is unclear  and is only subject to solve your own issue.

Comment: Reading the documentation on php.net reveals that readfile() will return the number of bytes read. So 615 is how large (in bytes) your file is.

Comment: Excellent answer, I was looking for a code and didn't pay attention to that part. That explains the 615. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Then after the bazillion and one check on the code I notices I made the mistake of including the file using a PHP short echo tag.

```
  <?= readfile("myfile.css") ?>
```

Big, big mistake, No need to echo a function that is already outputting to the buffer, I know, nevertheless this things happen once on awhile.

So finally:

```
<?php readfile("myfile.css") ?>
```

got rid of the 615, and thanks to rpaskett now I know the number corresponds to readfile() returning the number of bytes read.